# console.log not works

Tags: extjs4, console.log

Im using ExtJS 4, and when try print via js console with console.log, the messages not show. I use Firebug to see the js console.
An example:

```
...
init: function(){
   console.log('Controlador cargado.');
   this.control({
   'abm-grid-usuarios button[action=show]':{
      click: function(btn){
         console.log('Se clickeo el boton de vista.');
         btn.up('abm-grid-usuarios').verInfoUsuario();
      }
   }
   });
}
```

I load ext-dev.js, any idea ?.

Comment: does the other console.log statement show up? which one doesn't show up i guess is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require your controller in app config?

```
...
Ext.application({

    controllers: [
        "ControllerName"
    ],
...
```